# Xcode 15 print not showing in console when "Wait for executable to be launched"

Tags: xcode, xcode15

In Xcode 15 when in target i define "Wait for executable to be launched" and launch the app via a local notification, than no print statement is printed into the console

```
print("TEST")
```

i know i can use the OSLoger, but how to display the print message in the console in this case

[image]

Comment: i also found `print()` to not work after a `Detach` and subsequent re-`Attach`. for the non-print-to-debug-console case, i ended up replacing `print()` with a light-weight logger which could output to either `print()` and/or write a text file. text file updates similar to what one might expect from the debug console.